# AJAX calls from RSS or similar functionality

Tags: php, ajax, rss, feed, voting

A website I'm making has an RSS feed of the posts that are submitted. On the website itself users can vote on submissions. However, it would be very convenient for them to vote straight from the RSS feed, since most of them read the posts from it.

This could be acheived by inserting hyperlinks into RSS feed items, which would point to pages that would register the votes. However, this way each vote would require the user to either leave the feed page or open a link in a new window.

Is it possible in any way to get rid of this constraint and let the user vote on the submissions without leaving the page with the RSS feed? (As if it was an AJAX call - which seems to be impossible to implement with RSS)

Comment: As long as the page the link leads to is quick and efficient, I wouldn't mind clicking a link in a feed.

Comment: Well, I thought it might lead to the submission page so that the user could also check out the comments.

Comment: As long as I don't have to do more than clicking the link and the page loads fast, it doesn't matter what's there. If I for example had to click on the link and then look for the vote button and such, or if it took a long time to load hundreds of comments I potentially did not care about, then it would be more of a hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible in any way to get rid of this constraint and let the user vote on the submissions without leaving the page with the RSS feed?

No. Expect most RSS clients to strip JavaScript from data before rendering pages. (Leaving it in would be a security problem, imagine having a "Send all the cookies from this page to my evil server" being sent to Google Reader users).

Comment: An iFrame, perhaps, then? Videos can be embedded, can't they? - Can't some type of control element be embedded the same way?